# How to Set the content for HttpResponseMessage during a unit test?

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am writing a unit test in which I am testing a service that connects to an external service.

Service code:

```cs
var request = new APIRequest
{
    Query = query
};

var response = await _httpService.SendRequestAsync(_configuration.ApiUrl, HttpMethod.Post, request, _configuration.Username, _configuration.Password);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>();
    return result;
}
```

The unit test that I have written for the above service method.

```cs
public async void GetPerformance_OKResults()
{
    //ARRANGE
    var resultToReturn = MockedEntitiesRepository.mockNetworkResult;
    HttpResponseMessage mockResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    mockResponse.Content = new ObjectContent(Type.GetType(resultToReturn), resultToReturn, MediaTypeFormatter.)

    mockHttpService.Setup(s => s.SendRequestAsync(applicationConfiguration.Object.Value.ApiUrl, HttpMethod.Post, It.IsAny<object>(), applicationConfiguration.Object.Value.Username, applicationConfiguration.Object.Value.Password)).Returns(Task.FromResult(mockResponse));

    service = new Service(applicationConfiguration.Object, mockHttpService.Object, mockLogger.Object, mockCacheService.Object);

    //ACT
    var result = await Service.GetPerformance(It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>(), It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>(), It.IsAny<string>());

    // ASSERT
    Assert.Collection(result, item => Assert.Equal(something, something));
}
```

I want to set the object `mockResponse`  HTTPResponseMessage content with the object `resultToReturn`  in the unit test so that when the code goes makes an actual call it is able to set the value and i can assert on the result.

How can I set the value?

Answer (score 9):

> How can I set the value?

Set the `Content` property to a `StringContent` that contains a JSON serialized `Result`, e.g.:

```
var result = new Result();
...
mockResponse.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```